# Python regex expression and return an array

Tags: python, regex

Example string:

```
ABCDX PPP [ATT:A01AD05 B01AC06 N02BA01] [KP:CCC LLL DDD]
```

What would be a suitable regex to first detect `ATT` in the string and then split the three

```
ATT:A01AD05 B01AC06 N02BA01
```

and return an array/list. Then also extract the `ABCDX PPP` part only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this perhaps?

```
import re

str = 'ABCDX PPP [ATT:A01AD05 B01AC06 N02BA01]'
matched = re.search('([\S\s]+?)\s\[.*?(ATT:\S+)\s*(\S+)\s*(\S+)', str)
if matched:
    tokens = matched.groups()
    print tokens
```

**EDIT:** As per new constraint:

```
import re

str = 'ABCDX PPP [ATT:A01AD05 B01AC06 N02BA01]'
matched = re.search('([\S\s]+?)\s\[.*?(ATT:[^\]]+)', str)
if matched:
    first = matched.group(1)
    result = matched.group(2).split(' ')
    result[0:0] = [first]
    print result
```

Comment: @user2669020 Awesome! Glad it helped ^^

Comment: actually there is a bit of a problem with the code that i can't seem to understand. The code does work for the above string but it fails to work for "ASDF CVBV [HSA:1128] [KO:K04129] [ATT:S01EB08 S01EB02 S01EB06 S01EB07]" Where there are more than 3 ATT codes. I see the problem but is there a dynamic way of setting this rather than hard coding to three only.

Comment: @user2669020 Edited my answer to handle multiple ATT codes

Answer (score 1):

for the first part

```
import re

myString = 'ABCDX PPP [ATT:A01AD05 B01AC06 N02BA01]'
pattern = r'ATT:.+\]'

match = re.search(pattern, myString)
matchList = str(match.group()).rstrip(']').split(' ')
print(matchList)
```

For the second part, everything is mostly the same except the expression to use is r'\w+\s\w+\s['  and you will need to change the rstrip to rstrip(' [')

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the comment but the code does not work for ABCD [HSA:1128] [KO:K04129] [ATT:S01EB08 S01EB02 S01EB06 S01EB07] string. It gives the following error:matchList = str(match.group()).rstrip(']').split(' ')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
import re

sample = 'ABCDX PPP [ATT:A01AD05 B01AC06 N02BA01] [KP:CCC LLL DDD]'
pattern = '''
        ^(\S+\s\S+)\s # Matches "ABCDX PPP"
        \[ATT:        # Matches [ATT:
        (\S+)\s+      # Matches A01AD05
        (\S+)\s+      # Matches B01AC06
        (\S+)\]       # Matches N02BA01
        '''
matched = re.search(pattern, sample, re.VERBOSE)
if matched:
    tokens = matched.groups()
    print tokens
```

Output:

```
('ABCDX PPP', 'A01AD05', 'B01AC06', 'N02BA01')
```

## Discussion

- I took advantage of a feature in the `re` module to create a self-document regular expression, namely the `re.VERBOSE` flag. This flag allows for arbitrary white space and comment within the expression, thus enhance readability.
- The left and right square brackets have special meaning in a regular expression, which is why I escaped them as `\[` and `\]`
- At the end of the code, `tokens` holds a tuple of four strings, see the output.

Comment: it does not work for the following string:PPP ABC [HSA:1128] [KO:K04129] [ATT:S01EB08 S01EB02 S01EB06 S01EB07]

Comment: What if i have more or less than 3 Matches.